# Github Actions workflow "ignores" my Heroku deployment while other jobs run completely fine

Tags: heroku, github-actions

I was trying to understand the CI/CD flow from this tutorial by [Indian Pythonista](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTofttoD2xg&ab_channel=IndianPythonista) and after following the tutorial and setting the Heroku app name and token in the Github Secrets I ran the yaml file below.

```
name: Python application

on: [push]


jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - run: |
        git fetch --prune --unshallow
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        export PYTHONPATH=src
        pytest
    - name: Deploy to Heroku
      env:
        HEROKU_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_TOKEN }}
        HEROKU_APP_NAME: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_APP_LINKNAME }}
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && job.status == 'success'
      run: |
        git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_TOKEN@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git
        git push heroku HEAD:master -f
```

The build looked like the screenshot below:
[image]

I do not exactly know what should I call this error as well, since I am new to the topic. Due to this, the flask app doesn't get updated on the Heroku app link as well.

Comment: Was that unexpected? Your Heroku deploy is *conditional*; was the condition met?

Comment: As per the tutorial, the heroku deployment should take place in the build and the flask app should have been pushed on the heroku app link. Can you tell me more about `github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'` ?

Comment: Did you read the docs? See e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#determining-when-to-use-contexts.

Comment: I read the docs and removed the `ref` condition above and it worked!(?) But it leaves me confused, because I want it to deploy to heroku only if I make changes in the master branch. ***Is it because during my git push I mention only `git push` and not `git push origin master`?

Comment: Why would the workflow care how you write your push? All it knows is what's made it to GitHub. You only need to do `git push <remote> <branch>` if there's no tracking set, or you want to push to a remote/branch other than that specified by the tracking setting. I'd guess the success part is wrong, in those docs it suggests using `${{ success() }}` but I'd only expect it to run that if everything else had worked anyway.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Did you try using `if ${{ success() && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}`?

Comment: Github changed the branch name master to main